# Physics-based simulation of car model using turtle in python

Tags: python, animation

In python, I can use the turtle module to move a car forward or turn it. I am calling the arrow head provided by the turtle module as the car. I am interested in simulating more realistic dynamic control models.

The capability needed for this is to control the speed of moving forward or backward and turning left or right. I used the turtle `speed` command.

```
import turtle             
wn = turtle.Screen()       
car = turtle.Turtle()     
car.speed(5) 
car.forward(50)          
wn.mainloop()
```

Using this code, I move the car forward, and I can assign any speed to it that i want. But this speed is constant for the entire length of journey. I want to simulate acceleration/deceleration, i.e. change of speed. I want the `speed` parameter to vary at each time-step of the animation. The change of speed will be dictated by dynamic laws. How to do that?

If this is not possible in turtle, how to implement such an animation in python? Even if this is possible, what are the other alternatives in python which are more physics and dynamics aware by design?

Comment: You may want to look into a game physics engine like Pygame.

Comment: @paisanco Yes it seems to have several games simulating physics of motion. I then guess a good browsing of codes there should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

`shape.addcomponent(turtle.get_poly(), 'red')`

Something to that effect